# I need to get information from XML document in C# XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes>
    <route routeNumber = "1">
        <routeName>Route1</routeName>
        <point pointNumber = "1">
            <pointName>Warszawa </pointName>
            <time>10</time>
        </point>
        <point pointNumber = "2">
            <pointName>Gdynia </pointName>
            <time>15</time>
        </point>
    </route>
    <route routeNumber = "1">
        <routeName>Route1</routeName>
        <point pointNumber = "1">
            <pointName>Warszawa </pointName>
            <time>10</time>
        </point>
        <point pointNumber = "2">
            <pointName>Gdynia </pointName>
            <time>15</time>
        </point>
    </route>
</routes>
```

And I have 3 classes:

1) `Route` class:

```
public class Route
{
    public int routeNumber { get; set; }
    public string routeName { get; set; }
    List<Point> pointList;

    public Route(int routeNumber, string routeName, list<Point> pointList)
    {
        this.routeNumber = routeNumber;
        this.routeName = routeName;
        this.pointList = pointList;
    }
}
```

2) `Point` class:

```
public class Point
{
    public int pointNumber { get; set; }
    public string pointName { get; set; }
    public int time { get; set; }

    public Point(int pointNumber, string pointName, int time )
    {
        this.pointNumber = pointNumber;
        this.pointName = pointName;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

3) `XmlReader` class:

```
public XmlReader
{
    public List<Route> GetXml()
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("dane.xml");
        List<Route> route = (
            from route in xml.Root.Elements("route")
            select new Route(
                int.Parse(route.Attribute("routeNumber").Value),
                route.Element("routeName").Value
            ).ToList<Route>();
        return route;
    }
}
```

When we move out list of points from class `Route`, my method `GetXml` return me list of routes with it's names and numbers. But I need to get list of `Points` for every route, with point's number, point's name and time. How can I do this?

I edit XmlReader clas to:

```
public XmlReader
{
    public List<Route> GetXml()
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("dane.xml");
        List<Route> route = (
            from route in xml.Root.Elements("route")
            select new Route(
                int.Parse(route.Attribute("routeNumber").Value),
                route.Element("routeName").Value,
                    (
                       from point
                       in
                             xml
                             .Descendants()
                             .Elements("point")
                       select new Point(
                            int.Parse(point.Attribute("pointNumber").Value),
                            point.Element("pointName").Value,
                            int.Parse(point.Element("time").Value)
                            )
                        ).ToList<Point>()
            ).ToList<Route>();
        return route;
    }
}
```

But now in route I get list of all points. How to change code to get only list of points from one route in each route?

Comment: Why aren't you deserializing with a serializer such as [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)?

Comment: Add the following pointlist to the Route constructor : route.Elements("point").Select(x => new Point() { pointNumber = (int)x.Attribute("pointNumber"), name = (string)x.Element("pointname"), time = (int)x.Elememt("time)}).ToList()